# A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Decripting with ECC**
I have a problem with decription on this file, can some one help me? I i'm using ECC enter image description here

Code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;



namespace eccdh_Forme.ECC
{
    public class ECCDH
    {


        public static byte[] Enkripto(byte[] key, string MesazhiSekret)
        {

            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            key=aes.Key;
            byte[] iv = aes.IV;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


            // Encrypt the message 
            using (MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ciphertext, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] plaintextMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MesazhiSekret);
                cs.Write(plaintextMessage, 0, plaintextMessage.Length);
                cs.Close();
                byte[] cipherMesazhi = ciphertext.ToArray();
                return cipherMesazhi;
            }



        }
        public static byte[] Dekripto(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] bobKey)//e shtuar e re mja pasu vleren
        {
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] message; 
            bobKey=aes.Key;
            byte[] iv = aes.IV;

                // Decrypt the message 
            using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
               {
                  using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
                        cs.Close();                      
                        message = plaintext.ToArray();                    


                    }
                }

                return message;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The program is stoping the compile wen i try to decript the text on this line of code " cs.Close(); ".
The form decription is this: 
[image]

Comment: Everything you need is in the exception.  Yet you refuse to copy the full contents of the exception and paste them into an [edit].  Why do you hate us so?

Comment: Can i send you the full project and to see the problem? in new in C# in this project is for education. Can you help me please? when yes i can uploar on dropbox and sher the link here

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here, but the one mostly likely causing your exception is you are assigning the key backwards. This:

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] message; 
bobKey=aes.Key;
byte[] iv = aes.IV;
```

You're setting your parameter's value to a random AES key. You probably meant to do this:

```
aes.Key = bobKey;
```

---

Other things:

1. You seem to be trying to use an initialization vector. I'm not sure why you're capturing it, but in ECB mode there is no initialization vector.
2. I'm going to assume that this is a learning exercise for yourself to understand how encryption and key exchanges work. That's great! Happy learning, but keep in mind there are a number of security issues here. The main one being that you're using ECB, and no MAC. Before you run off to put this in a production system, if that is the intention, I would consider using a much more high-level approach so the key exchange is transparent to you.

Comment: Can i send you the full project and to see the problem?
in new in C# in this project is for education. Can you help me please?
when yes i can uploar on dropbox and sher the link here

Comment: Whoda seen that coming?!?